# Ionic 4 - IOS - Google map native crash

Tags: ios, google-maps, native, ionic4

I'm looking to someone having trouble when using Google Map Native plugin with IOS.

Everything works fine with the browser and Android.

The crash on IOS appears when performing

```
this.map = GoogleMaps.create("map_canvas");
```

This is not really a crash. The app quit, go to the home screen of my iPhone and the app still in background. I can rerun it but "crash" again.

There is no error messages, and a simple Try Catch doesn't catch the problem (and the crash always).

Any solution about that ?

Comment: @ionic-native/google-maps or @ionic-native/google-maps/ngx ? I tried both

Comment: same here also. Did you find any solution?